# Why do string commands via `R -e ..` on Mac vs Linux requires an extra escape?

Tags: r, linux, macos, shell, amazon-linux

This one stumped me.  I have a simple shell script executing that works fine on my Linux (*AWS* aka *CentOS*) machine but crashed on my *Mac OS X* machine. It turned out escapes (`\`) in string commands needed an extra escape character (`\\`).

***Could someone enlighten me as to what I am missing here -- ie, what is it about running the R scripts on Macs that require this?***

The behavior was **not** observed when calling, say, `python3 -c ..`

On both machines, I am using `bash`, specifically `/bin/bash`

*NOTE: The Mac is a slightly later version of R:  3.5.1 vs 3.4.1, but I would be strongly surprised if that was the culprit. Anyone available to confirm?*

---

#### Simple Example:

```
R --vanilla -e 'cat(" Hello \n World \n ")'
```

The above runs fine on a CentOS machine, but requires an additional escape character (`\\n` instead of `\n`) to execute correctly. *(example at bottom)*

For reference/comparison, the following python command works identically on each of the Mac OS X, CentOS machines I tested.

```
python3 -c 'print("Hello \n World")'
```

---

---

**For details, here is the output comparing the two commands on each of the two machines**

```
1. R --vanilla -e 'cat(" Hello \n World \n ")'
2. R --vanilla -e 'cat(" Hello \\n World \\n ")'
```

### 1.

```
R --vanilla -e 'cat(" Hello \n World \n ")'

## CENTOS: 
> cat(" Hello \n World \n ")
 Hello
 World

## MAC OS X:
> cat(" Hello
+
+ Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted
```

### 2.

```
R --vanilla -e 'cat(" Hello \\n World \\n ")'

## CENTOS: 
> cat(" Hello \\n World \\n ")
 Hello \n World \n >

## MAC OS X:
> cat(" Hello \n World \n ")
 Hello
 World
```

**For comparison's sake, I'm not seeing the same behavior when running a simple python script.**

```
## Each of these produce identical 
##  results in Mac OSX as CentOS

python3 -c 'print("Hello \n World")'
python3 -c 'print("Hello \\n World")'
```

---

---

### Machine & Session Info:

1. Linux Box

```
> cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"

> R --vanilla -e 'sessionInfo()'
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1
```

2. Mac OS Box

```
Mojave 10.14.3

> R --vanilla -e 'sessionInfo()'
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1
```

3. Another Mac OSX machine, running 3.4.3, same error

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That's why I included the python example. If it was related to the shell, I would have expected the same behavior for both Python & R.  I think the issue is R related.  But no, not using `fish`, just `bash` in both cases.  I will edit the question

Comment: BTW, I can't reproduce the behavior -- with R version 3.5.1 installed via Nixpkgs, I get the same behavior on MacOS you report for Linux.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  that's very interesting, thank you. I can't update my CentOS machine, but I will try to spin up a new one.

Comment: ...so, looking at the `R` wrapper shell script, it's pretty ugly in there (as in, rampant [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) violations) -- I'd need to dig in more to say anything conclusive, but it certainly *smells* like they could have introduced some bugs.

Comment: ...as a pull quote, the `R` wrapper script executes `exec "${R_binary}"  ${args} "${@}"`. That's... well, follow the BashFAQ #50 link in the above comment for a description of why unquoted `$args` is a practice nobody should ever, ever use.

Comment: One thing you can try is cutting the wrapper out of the picture on both operating systems and seeing if that solves the problem. Does `R_HOME=/usr/lib/R /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R -e 'cat(" Hello \n World \n ")'` behave consistently, after you fix up the paths to be correct for each platform?

Comment: On your MacOS systems, by the way, which version of `sed` is in your PATH -- the host's BSD `sed`, or GNU `sed` installed with Nix/MacPorts/Homebrew/etc? (Though if that *were* related to the problem, bypassing the wrapper as suggested above should also avoid it).

Comment: (...to be very clear, btw, the use of `sed` to munge command lines in R's wrapper script is an abomination, but that's neither here nor there; it *exists*, in the current implementation).

Comment: Could the version of Bash be relevant here, i.e. the escape behavior have changed in some version and on your macOS its an older version? `bash --version`

Comment: @HenrikB, I describe earlier in the comments (ed: in now-deleted comments, oops) why the version of bash is not relevant -- interpretation between single-quoted strings is identical between all POSIX-compliant shells. And `bash --version` is the wrong way to check anyhow; it tells you which version is first in the PATH, not which version is currently running; thus, on MacOS, it shows any newer interpreter installed with Nix/MacPorts/Homebrew, even if Apple's `/bin/bash` is currently in use.

Comment: Maybe this issue should be sent to the [R-SIG-Mac](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac) mailing list.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thxs.  1. I noticed that you could not reproduce OPs observations, whereas OP could do it on two different systems. That's some kind of clue. 2. My point was that there _could_ be a bug/bug fix/change in Bash that reveals itself in one version but not another - would be useful to rule out. 3. Is there a way to query the version of the _running_ bash?  4. I agree with your concerns about the `R` script.  5. Running [ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) on it (and other scripts such as `build`, `INSTALL`, and `check`) reveals this and other potential problems

Comment: I had a look at the R script; it uses `sed` to process commandline arguments. As mentioned `Charles Duffy` the macOS (BSD) version of `sed` may have something to do with this. BSD `sed` seems to not accept control sequences `\n` and `\t` (see [this](https://riptutorial.com/sed/topic/9436/bsd-macos-sed-vs--gnu-sed-vs--the-posix-sed-specification)). This could explain the needed double escapes. However I may be completely wrong.

Comment: @HenrikB, one likely reason I couldn't reproduce the behavior they stated for MacOS is that I'm using a (Nix-provided) GNU `sed` even on MacOS. Answering your other question: To check the *running* version of bash, `declare -p BASH_VERSION` will do.

Comment: @Bhas, I agree. If the OP tried bypassing the wrapper script (and thus bypassing `sed`) by executing `R/bin/exec/R` directly, that should be able to rule out that theory (or increase its likelihood, by isolating the wrapper or something it calls as the source of the variance).

Answer (score 4):

Following up on my suggestion that the cause of the problem could be the difference between macOS `sed` and GNU `sed` and [Charles Duffy's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228434/why-do-string-commands-via-r-e-on-mac-vs-linux-requires-an-extra-escape?noredirect=1#comment97195889_55228434) as last comment on the original question I have tried calling the R executable directly on macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and with R 3.5.3 as follows in a shell script:

```
export R_HOME=$(R RHOME)
Rexec=${R_HOME}/bin/exec/R

$Rexec --vanilla -e 'cat(" Hello \n World \n ")'
```

And this will not give error messages and give the same output as on Linux.

In my opinion the issue is not a bug in bash but a regrettable difference between macOS (BSD) and GNU `sed`. I don't have a clue how this could be corrected in the R wrapper script, if possible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Thanks for the improvement to my answer.

Comment: np; thank you for doing the experiment to confirm. Personally, my fix would be to rewrite the wrapper to not use sed -- the easiest ways to avoid unquoted expansion are to use arrays as BashFAQ #50 suggests, but one could probably also get the same effect through in-place manipulation of `"$@"` in a POSIX-compliant way. Beyond the scope of this question, though; I think you've answered it well.